# Как сохранить get запрос в бд Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Написал небольшой метод, который должен добавлять комменты, к конкретным записям в бд.

Создал таблицу comments с полями:
**comment_id** - idшник коммента
**author_id** - id перца, который комментит
**post_id** - idшник поста, который комментят
**comment** - сам коммент

Сам метод:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->author_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $request->post;

    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Комментарий добавлен');    
}
```

Я хочу, что бы в базу, сохранялся id поста, который комментируют, id поста беру из get запроса. Зашел в свой blade шаблон, и написал там `{{ request()->post }}`, в итоге у меня на экране отобразился id нужной записи, пытаюсь сохранить этот id'шник строкой `$comment->post_id = $request->post;`, в итоге получаю ошибку, о том что post_id null `Column 'post_id' cannot be null`

Как мне правильно сделать?

Comment: Что выдаёт `var_dump($request)`? Можешь добавить blade шаблон, возможно, ты не отправляешь данные в запросе?

Comment: `dd($request->all());` - покажет всё, что вы получаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то в POST запросе из формы в шаблоне не приходит вот эта строчка

```
$comment->post_id = $request->post;
```

Если это так, то решение
1. В blade шаблоне - добавляете в форму, которая отрпавляет данные, скрытое инпут поле с вашими данными ( request()->post ) :

```
 <input type="hidden" value={{ request()->post }} name='post_id'>
```

2. В store методе контроллера достаете эти данные из $request

   $comment->post_id = ($request->has('post_id')) ? $request->get('post_id') : null;

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `$request->input('post');`